# how to fix 'int' object is not iterable error in python?

Tags: python

I have to write a code in python that gets a string as an input from the user and add a dot before each character of the string as an output.
this is the code I wrote, but I faced this error:

for letter in len(vroodi):

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Can anyone help me fix the error?

```
vroodi = str(input("Enter the string"))
def insert_dot(q, harf):
    e= vroodi[ :harf] + "." +vroodi[harf: ]
    return e
for letter in len(vroodi):
    r = insert_dot(vroodi, letter)
print(r)
```

Comment: I see that your `print(r)` is outside of the loop. This means it only will print the last result.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in len('string')` Is the same thing as saying `for i in 6` and in Python you cannot iterate through an integer/float.

What instead you should do is create an iterable out of `len('string')`.

```
for i in range(len('string')):
```

Or since `vroodi` is a string, you can just iterate over it.

```
for i in vroodi:
```

Comment: Except that his `insert_dot()` expects an integer to do its slices.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all the characters in the string.
If you want a numeric index corresponding to the characters, use

```
for idx in range(len(vroodi)):
```

As your loop (it loops from 0 to length of string - 1)